# How can i use my own rig to input into mixamo and get animated fbx. My blender fbx is not getting imported in mixamo

Tags: rigify, mixamo

i have a blender model with rig (face rigged through auto rig pro and body rigged by rigify). I want to use this model and armature in mixamo to animate it and download the animated fbx. But when i export the fbx from blender with textures and armature, the resulting file is unable to get imported in mixamo (i get error - cannot map the file, in mixamo).

I want the armature and model both because its weight painted properly in blender. I can get an obj or fbx into mixamo without armature (although there is texture and color loss there), but mixamo auto rigger does not do a very good job in rigging the model.

Can anyone please help as to why the armature and model both are not being imported in mixamo. Or is there anything else i can do, so that i can use my weight painted model in blender and still utilize the keyframes downloaded from mixamo.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that you can upload your own rig to be used for animation in Mixamo. There is an [addon from Mixamo for Blender](https://substance3d.adobe.com/plugins/mixamo-in-blender/) that adds controls to the downloaded rig for easy animation. But if you want to use the existing rig you can use an addon for retargeting that supports Rigify and Mixamo. For example [ExpyKit 0.5](https://youtu.be/auTkEEK6Dmo) by *BallsAndNinjas*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Can you please help me with why i am unable to import the FBX file exported from this blend file to mixamo. I have tried multiple settings in Blender export but the resulting FBX is not imported in mixamo.

Comment: Oh, it's the teddy bear! I see you have improved his mesh topology. It looks great. The upload to Mixamo works for me if I only upload the mesh. In the export dialog, you can limit the exported objects to the selection and also to certain types like "Mesh".

Comment: Hey, full disclosure, someone else made this mesh for me :D. Although, i was able to map  a simple human metarig from blender to this character, and then upload both mesh and armature as an fbx to mixamo. It worked perfectly and i was able to get an animated fbx out from mixamo and use in blender for animation.

Now i need to figure out how to use the facial rig as well. So the person who made mesh for me rigged the body using rigify and face through auto rig pro. I am yet to learn face rigging.

Comment: Not sure if the original face rig can be added as it is to the mixamo rigged version.

Comment: The following link to a YouTube tutorial helped me upload my genesis character up to Mixamo, maybe you could learn from it to upload your character [YouTube video on how to upload genesis character to Mixamo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1_Cysg6kI4) You can see by the following screenshot, that the character is now available for me on log in to apply any mixamo animation [![mixamo login screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgHO3.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgHO3.jpg) I personally would like to learn how to make my own "mixamo compliant" animated files, then the sky would no longer be